# Single-frequency AM Receiver?

Tags: transistors, rf, antenna, radio, amplitude-modulation

Previously today, I tried to make an extremely simple AM receiver without a tuner. It didn't really work (I'm still trying to work on it), but I also tried to make an AM receiver that is tuned to one single frequency (approximately 960 kHz).

I made this circuit on a breadboard (except the 100 ohm resistor), but it's not working. I can't hear anything at all. Can anyone give me any guidance?

To explain my circuit a little more, I just used 2 (and also tried 3) BC547 NPN transistors to amplify the signal, and used a diode to filter out the negative voltage. And my positive terminal and ground are just the positive and negative sides of a 9V battery. Also, my piezo buzzer is powered by DC voltage. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You need some dc bias on the first transistor

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry, I'm new at this.

Comment: Are you expecting to buzz the buzzer when there's signal?  Or are you expecting to hear a radio station?

Comment: Just buzz. @TimWescott

Comment: That receiver would need about 6-7V on the input to make a buzz; normal AM receivers deal with microvolts.

Comment: Hmm, so using a series of transistors as amplifiers for the buzzer won't work? That's what I tried to do; obtain the microvolt signal and increase both its voltage and current using BC547's and a 9V battery, to feed into the buzzer (which requires 1.5V minimum). @TimWescott

Comment: The amplifier in your schematic is a pair of emitter-followers in cascade.  It has no voltage gain, only current gain.  A pair of common-emitter amps might do better -- but it'd still be pretty lame.  A regenerative receiver could maybe work with just two transistors.

Comment: @TimWescott Even if the voltage isn't increased, wouldn't the voltage still be 9v for the buzzer since 9v was inputted into the transmitter collector? Therefore shouldn't it buzz? I'm still not sure. How would you make the schematic?

Comment: Do a web search on "emitter follower".

Comment: Did you examine the 2nd answer I provided to you, on the first question? That should work, but will response to ALL channels.